# My Surface Pro 4 suddenly doesn't turn on at all. Why is this happening?

Tags: microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I'm using my Surface Pro 4 normally by yesterday. The performance is i7 CPU, 8GB RAM and 256GB SSD.

I finished my homework with the Surface (just editing some Google Docs documents) and pressed the power button to let it sleep. However, when I tried to press the power button to turn on again, it had no response at all! I couldn't even hear the noise coming from the internal parts (machinery) at all, which means the Surface is not turning on at all, and it may be dead already.

I tried to press a combination of physical buttons for a long time, but it still didn't work and the screen didn't turn on. I expect that the battery was full because I always plug in the charger at home so that the battery won't drain while working, so it's not the problem from the battery draining.

Is there any possible methods I can try more to make it turn on before I report the problem to Microsoft? Unfortunately, the warranty period is already passed, so I won't get a free exchanged product.

Comment: Are you sure the device has a charge.  How long between using it was it?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on Microsoft Support https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023537/surface-surface-wont-turn-on-or-wake-from-sleep

> - If you have a keyboard connected, simultaneously press the Windows logo key  +Ctrl+Shift+B.
> - If you are in tablet mode, simultaneously press both the volume-up and volume-down buttons three times in quick succession (within two
>     seconds).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with mine, although I had selected shut down it must not have turned off, sleep and hibernate mode had been disabled, yet it behaved as though it was in a sleep/hibernate mode.

To start my Surface Pro 4 I held the power button down for about 20 seconds, then after another 5-10 seconds I pressed the power button again and It started up as normal.

I would suggest that you have it connected to the charger at the same time, in case your battery had not been charged correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had your problem by Surface Pro 3 and I used rubber band trick!!

I placed the popsicle stick flat against the power button and used the rubber band (you can use electric masking tape too) to apply pressure to keep the power button pressed the whole time (you can use the example picture to apply pressure on power button too). I can see the charger LED connected to my Surface coming on and off as the power cycled. No sign of the Surface waking up.

[image: an example picture to apply pressure on power button]

I came back 8 hours and noticed the charger LED didn't come on and off anymore. So, I pull the popsicle stick off and I pressed the power button and the Surface powered on!

It has occurred more and more until I reset the Windows by recover flash. I think that it was driver issues!?

---

**Update:** Yes, own surface had driver issues with type cover, when I detach the type cover the problem solved.

For more information, you can refer to [this link.](https://forums.windowscentral.com/microsoft-surface-pro-3/456016-surface-pro-3-wont-turn-back-possible-solution-when-all-hope-lost.html)